# Count the number of rows in a schema based on a where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have engine_id column in various tables in the schema. So I want to count the number of rows based on engine_id column in the whole schema where this column exists.

```
Select count(*) 
from table_name 
where table_name.engine_id = 8;
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle version is 12c

Comment: There are answers to your question just waiting for your acceptance. Choose one of them and click its check mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without user-defined PL/SQL, using only built-in Oracle functionality...

Oracle 11g (and maybe even lower) query:

```
select TC.table_name, X.*
from user_tab_columns TC
    cross join xmltable(
        '/ROWSET/ROW/CNT'
        passing
            dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType('
                select count(1) as cnt
                from '||TC.table_name||'
                where &columnName = &columnValueAsLiteral
            ')
        columns
            cnt integer
    ) X
where TC.column_name = '&columnName'
;
```

Oracle 12c+ query:

```
select TC.table_name, X.*
from user_tab_columns TC
    cross apply xmltable(
        '/ROWSET/ROW/CNT'
        passing
            dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType('
                select count(1) as cnt
                from '||TC.table_name||'
                where &columnName = &columnValueAsLiteral
            ')
        columns
            cnt integer
    ) X
where TC.column_name = '&columnName'
;
```

In your case supply

- `&columnName` as `ENGINE_ID`,
- `&columnValueAsLiteral` as `8`.

**Note:** It could also be possible with the [with-PLSQL clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJFIDC) of 12c's but I somehow can't make it work, hence I'm not posting that solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need PL code that would query the data dictionary view `USER_TABLES` to find out which tables have the column you seek and then build a dynamic SQL query as per your filter requirements.

Your function would be something like this:

```
create or replace function find_count (p_column_name varchar2,
                                       p_column_value number)
    return number is
    v_sql          clob; HERE
    v_count        number;
begin
    for i in (select table_name
                from user_tab_cols
               where column_name = upper(v_column_name)) loop
        v_sql                      :=
            v_sql
            || 'select count(*) as cnt from '
            || i.table_name
            || ' where '
            || p_column_name
            || ' = '
            || p_column_value;
        v_sql                      := v_sql || chr (10) || 'union all ';
    end loop;

    v_sql                      := substr (v_sql, 1, length (v_sql) - 11);

    v_sql                      := 'select sum(cnt) from (' || v_sql || ')';

    execute immediate v_sql into v_count;

    return v_count;
end find_count;
/
```

You can trigger this function using a query like this:

```
select find_count('ENTITY_ID', 1012) as engine_count from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps which you should be following

1. Get all the tables which have the column.

   ```
   select table_name from all_tab_columns
   where column_name = 'ENGINE_ID';
   ```
2. Create the above as a cursor and run a loop on it

   ```
   for records in above_cursor
   loop
       execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || records.table_name || 'where engine_id = 8' into some_temp_number_var;
       some_total_number_var := some_temp_number_var + some_total_number_var;
   end loop;
   ```